# Can't resolve image into URL: to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, rails-activestorage

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It is being called on my `edit` page:

```
<h1>Upload Avatar</h1>
  <%= image_tag(@user.avatar) %>
  <%= render 'form', user: @user %>
<hr>
```

I get the error in the title but I am not sure why the avatar is not being attachd to the `user` model. I have all the requirements done for `active_storage`.

`has_one_attached :avatar` in `user model`.

In `user controller`:

```
  def identity_params
    params.permit(:email_confirmation, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar).to_h.symbolize_keys.tap do |params|
      params[:email] = params[:email_confirmation]
    end 
  end
```

Also I have all the necessary migrations. Am I missing the actual avatar attaching logic?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can get the error message *"Can't resolve image into URL: to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil"* if you are trying to show in your view an attachment that does not exist:

```
<%= image_tag(@user.avatar) %>
```

to avoid error you should do this:

```
<%= image_tag(@user.avatar) if @user.avatar.attached? %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I meant I am not sure why it doesn't save the avatar to the database.

Comment: The issue was not having `user.avatar.attach(params['user']['avatar'])` in the `controller`.

Comment: What kind of storage are you using? local or cloud? cloud storage can have some issues with [CORS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors). Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @A.J in what controller? in the users controller?

Comment: BTW https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35613 I am facing this issue randomly in my development, even though the record was properly attached a file, and i can see insertions being made in active storage tables, but it somehow loses the attachment later on. It happens to some random records, not each record.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are missing configuration (because you don't mention it):

You must declare Active Storage services in `config/storage.yml`

Example from docs:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: ""
  secret_access_key: ""
```

and you must tell Active Storage which service to use by setting `Rails.application.config.active_storage.service`

> Because each environment will likely use a different service, it is recommended to do this on a per-environment basis. To use the disk service from the previous example in the development environment, you would add the following to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
# Store files locally.
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Comment: I had all if it set up. Sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: I am upgrading existing app. There is no such set up here. I found this answer useful.

Answer (score 2):

Soultion **if your user model id is UUID**

You need to modify `ActiveStorage` migration a bit by adding `type: :uuid` to ActiveStorage migration by `record` field

```
create_table :active_storage_attachments do |t|
  t.string     :name,     null: false
  t.references :record,   null: false, polymorphic: true, index: false, type: :uuid
  ...
```

reference https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same error due to the silly mistake. Actually I added the extra space to **local:** key. So make sure you are following the proper indentation. And should not miss the configuration. You must declare Active Storage services in config/storage.yml in the following way.

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: ""
  secret_access_key: ""
  bucket: ""
  region: "" # e.g. 'us-east-1'
```

Make sure in the environment/development.rb, environment/production.rb and environment/test.rb you have added the following line of code

```
config.active_storage.service = :local #environment/development.rb
config.active_storage.service = :amazon ##environment/production.rb
config.active_storage.service = :test #environment/test.rb
```